# Can I use Prometheus with scheduler or worker service in rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, prometheus

Can I use Prometheus when using resque-web or run worker?

The first service, I run rails server and use this at config.ru file.

> use Prometheus::Middleware::Collector
>
> use Prometheus::Middleware::Exporter.

But another service about resque-web and resque work.
I was doing research on this issue but I didn't get an idea to use Prometheus with them.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

To send metrics from background jobs to prometheus you can use the Pushgateway https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing. Now if you monitor request specifically you probably need an expoter targeted at it, googling it I found https://github.com/moznion/resque_exporter, but I've never used it. You could also write an exporter for resque if this one doesn't help you.

Comment: use comment for such posting